# Is the Lie bracket with an orthonormal basis $0$ always?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $(X_i)$ be an orthonormal basis and $(, )$ an inner product, then is the following true?

$(  [X_i, X_j], X_i )  = 0$?

I found that $(X_iX_j - X_jX_i,X_i) = X_iX_jX_i - X_jX_i^2$ So looks like if there is commutativty or depending on the inner product, the sum is $0$.

For example, define $(X,Y) = tr(XY)$ then it seems the basis does not need to be orthonormal to be $0.$

Let's say $X_i$ are matrices.

Comment: Are these vectors or matrices? you specified that (,) was an inner product but then just multiplied the objects together? This question needs to be made clearer.

Comment: @EHH, the objects in the vector space are called vectors, but the real objects are matrices.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by 'real' object?

Comment: @EHH, I mean that is what the objects are. The $(X_i)$ is a collection of square matrices which are all orthonormal with respect to the given inner product $(,)$

Comment: @JasonDeVito, but it appears to be true if we select an inner product $h$ such that the basis is orthogonal with respect to $h.$

Comment: If $h,x,y$ are the usual basis for $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$, then the killing form is an inner product for which this basis is orthogonal, and $[h,x]=2x$, so this is kind of as false as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E_{ij}$ denote the $2\times 2$ matrix with a $1$ in the $(i,j)$ slot and a $0$ elsewhere.  Then $E_{11}, E_{12}, E_{21}, E_{22}$ is clearly a basis for the space of all $2\times 2$ matrices (over whatever field you want.)

Then note that $[E_{11},E_{12}] = E_{12}$. Now, if $h$ denotes any inner product at all, then $h([E_{11},E_{12}], E_{12}) = h(E_{12}, E_{12}) > 0$.